# Publishing to Azure Data Factory from GitHub

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can someone remind why when I publish from Gitbhub my Synapse Live workspace isn't updated with with the Pipelines created in Github?

Answer (score 0):

Only when a pipeline is created in azure synapse analytics workspace's GIT mode, the pipeline would also appear in Synapse Live mode. Look at this [official Microsoft documentation's best practices section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/source-control#best-practices-for-git-integration:%7E:text=Best%20practices%20for%20Git%20integration) which indicates the same.

But when the pipeline exists in your GIT repository, then after integrating your GIT, this pipeline would only be seen in the GIT branch but not in the Synapse Live mode.

- Let's say I have the following pipeline in my repo.

[image]

- When I integrate this repo with my synapse workspace, this pipeline would only appear in GIT branch.

[image]

- You can see that it is not visible in synapse live mode.

[image]

- If you want your synapse live mode pipelines to GIT, you can check this option while configuring GIT and then publish to get them to your GIT.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This kind of things can happen when objects in your git repository get out of synch with the publish branch. (changes to linked services for example can be created imediately and create this kind of bad situation).
Meanwhile, there is at the moment a strange situation in Synapse that could also explain "weird behaviours". There seems to be a general bug causing 2 things :

- problems when publishing to synapse live.
- problems with notebook activity in pipelines : the reference to the notebook is lost and we are unable to select notebook in the pipeline activity

In my case i am waiting microsoft feedback on this